# Why does C++ standard queue have back function when stack doesn't have bottom function?

Tags: c++, stack, queue, std

On one of many unofficial C++ reference websites, there are listed member functions `front()` and `back()` for [`std::queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/). However, [`std::stack`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/) only has `top()` function.

It makes sense for the stack to not have a `bottom()` function because that's the definition of a stack.

What I don't get is why did the C++ standard committee chose not to follow the definition of a queue and provide with `back()` function for queue and chose to follow the definition of a stack and not provide with `bottom()` function.

Comment: This might sound be a bit pedantic, but cplusplus.com is not *the* C++ reference. It's *a* (= some) website about C++.

Comment: Hmm... `stack::bottom` is not really analogous to `queue::back`. I don't think supplying `back` is really an interesting violation. You are still limited to `push_back` and `pop_front`, fulfilling the expectations of a FIFO queue.

Comment: Adding stack::bottom still fulfills LIFO, too.

Comment: @dyp what do you suggest as an alternative reference? The standard itself is paywalled and not deep-linkable.

Comment: @Adam You can use [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), which is the Standard plus purely editorial changes, or the latest C++1y draft (e.g. via the [github repository](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft)) which also contains some fixes that the compilers will implement in their C++11 mode (sic!). There's also another (= some) website [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) which has a good reputation in the StackOverflow C++ community.

Comment: @whiteSkar Are you asking about the name of that function? I.e. why is there no `back()` function instead/alongside `top()` in `std::stack`?

Comment: @dyp Nope. I am asking why queue has accessors for both sides when stack only has accessor for one side when both data structures are only one way push and back structures.

Comment: Because a queue can be double-ended.

Comment: @EJP the queue structure in STL is single-ended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There might be other reasons for `back()`, but you needed it for a queue because of the idiom from C++03 of cheaply copying an "empty" object into a container and then `swap`ping that new element with a "full" object that would be very expensive to copy. This reason is more or less obsolete in C++11 thanks to move semantics, but of course `back()` is still needed for compatibility.

You don't need `bottom()` for a stack for that (or any other) reason.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why copying an empty object and then swapping need a back() function or link to where I can read about it?

Other than that, this seems like the answer, Thanks

Comment: @whiteSkar example: think a queue of vectors. Let's say each vector has thousands or more elements. To push `v` onto `q`, you could do `q.push(v)`, but this would copy the entire vector. Instead, `q.push(vector<int>()); q.back().swap(v);`. This simply swaps the pointers, it doesn't actually touch any vector elements. If `v` isn't used after the push, then this method is much faster.

Comment: @Adam: You can also do `q.push(std::move(v));`

Comment: @BenVoigt in C++11 definitely, but Steve's talking about C++03.

Answer (score 1):

It actually makes sense in a weird way. In a queue, you push on one side and pop from the other so both sides are very likely to change a lot. With a stack, you push and pop both from the top, and the bottom of the stack very rarely changes. So, it's rarely interesting to query the current value of the bottom of a stack.

Comment: But after you push you're not supposed to be able to see that pushed element until it's made it to the front of the queue.

Comment: @Lightness: It's useful for debugging purposes, to see internal elements.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm not disputing that access to non-front elements would be _great_ for debugging (and anyway, as Steve says, there are actually some important real-world use cases for it that go beyond debugging); just the claim that it makes any sort of semantic sense.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: That's true, but there are many queue based algorithms where it's useful to decide whether or not to push a new item based on the last pushed item. There aren't many stack based algorithms where you can make useful decision based on what's in the bottom of the stack.